# Django migrations. How to check if table exists in migrations?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm currently working on app built on Django 1.8 and Postgres. This app is installed in several environments, in some of them there old tables in DB from which i need to delete records.

I wrote migration with following SQL query:

```
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT relname FROM pg_class WHERE relname=tablename
) THEN 
    DELETE FROM tablename END IF;
```

But Django throws error at this query:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "IF"
```

Can i somehow check, in migration, that table exists, and only then execute query, like `DROP FROM tablename` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it using `django.db.connection`. Code:

```
from django.db import migrations
from django.db import connection


class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    db_cursor = connection.cursor()
    check_exists_query = "SELECT relname FROM pg_class WHERE relname=%s;"
    base_query = "DELETE FROM {table} WHERE condition;"
    tables = [tables]
    existing_tables = []

    for table in tables:
        db_cursor.execute(check_exists_query, [table])
        result = db_cursor.fetchone()
        if result:
            existing_tables.append(table)

    operations = [
        migrations.RunSQL(base_query.format(table=existing_table)) for existing_table in existing_tables
    ]
```

Comment: this would empty all your tables. So that begs the question, why not drop the database instead?

Comment: agree, not the most useful example. Updated delete query with `WHERE` condition

Answer (score 12):

The easiest way to check if a table exists is to use `django.db.connection.introspection.table_names()`:

```
from django.db import connection

...

all_tables = connection.introspection.table_names()
old_tables = set('old_table_1', 'old_table_2')
existing_old_tables = old_tables.union(all_tables)
# clean tables in existing_old_tables with migrations.RunSQL() as suggested above
```

Comment: This one is very useful when you have `Model.objects.query()` inline before migrations has `ProgramingError` but this prevented by `django.db.connection.introspection.table_names()`
for example:
`Model.objects.query() if django.db.connection.introspection.table_names() else []`